# Prove that limit superior is the largest limit point of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that  limit superior is the largest limit point of a sequence.

My attempt:

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that it has +∞ as a limit point. Then it has no finite upper bound. This means that the sequence diverges.  Let $L^+$ be the limit superior of this sequence. This implies that $L^+$ is finite. Then, for every x>$L^+$, the elements of the sequence are eventually less than x.

I don't know if i am going in the right direction with my proof

Comment: In fact, I prefer the definition of $\limsup a_n$ as the largest subsequential limit of $(a_n).$ Seems very natural compared to the usual one.

Answer (score 2):

If $b$ is a limit point, then there is a subsequence such that $a_{n_k} \to b$.

Assume $ b > L = \limsup a_n$.

Since $a_{n_k} \to b$ then for any $\epsilon  > 0$ there exists $N$ such that if $k > N$ we have $b - \epsilon < a_{n_k} < b + \epsilon.$   Choose $\epsilon = (b-L)/2$, then $b - \epsilon = (b+L)/2$, and there must be infinitely many $a_{n_k} > (b+L)/2 > L.$  This contradicts the fact that $L = \limsup a_n$ and we must have all but finitely many $a_n < (b+L)/2 > L$.

Comment: How do you know If $ b > L = \limsup a_n$, then there must be infinitely many $a_{n_k} > (b+L)/2 > L.$

Comment: Since $a_{n_k} \to b$ then for any $\epsilon  > 0$ there exists $N$ such that if $k > N$ we have $b - \epsilon < a_{n_k} < b + \epsilon.$   Choose $\epsilon = (b-L)/2$, then $b - \epsilon = (b+L)/2$.

Comment: I expanded the answer to clarify for you.